# On-load animation for Google pie charts

Tags: google-visualization

Does Google Visualization allow on-load animations for pie charts? So far I have only been able to get on-load animations for column charts, but not for pie charts, bar charts, line charts or even a Google table chart for that matter.

this is the pie chart that I am trying to animate on-load:

```
<div id="piechart" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                        function drawChart() {

                            var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                              ['FacultyName', 'SubmissionID'],
                               @Html.Raw(rows)]);
                            var options = {
                                title: '',
                                animation: {
                                    duration: 1000,
                                    startup: true
                                }
                            };
                            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
                            chart.draw(data1, options);
                    </script>
```

However the animate option doesn't seem to take place.

Comment: `animation` isn't listed in the [configuration options](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options) --> must not be available for pie chart

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a configuration option @Kivan. However, I was able to animate it based on this code [jsfiddle-damithz](http://jsfiddle.net/damithz/k8d93vyd/) here: [jsfiddle-pawr](https://jsfiddle.net/PawrOH/dL95po4m/20/). Hope it helps someone else. I was spinning my wheels for a while trying to get the data to load correctly.

Comment: @Pawr while the percentage is correct in your example the amount is not correct.